# the use of value >> i << i != value:

Tags: python

I encountered such a function:

```
import math
import random

def low_zeros(value):
    for i in xrange(1, 32):
        if value >> i << i != value:
            break
    return i - 1
```

I googled but not found any useful material about `value >> i << i != value:`

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: what is input and expected output?

Comment: This is equivalent to `((value >> i) << i) != value`

Comment: If you want to know what the said line does, its checking if number is a power of 2 or not. Its left shifting which is division by 2 and right shifting by which is x2, so number will be same if it is a multiple of 2 only, else will break.

Comment: @warl0ck not quite. Even multiples of two can break (consider `2` itself when `i > 1`, or `4` when `i > 2`, or `8` when `i > 3` or...)

Comment: @AdamSmith, sorry I meant was pure multiples of 2, (i.e. power of 2 only), please correct me if wrong

Comment: @warl0ck I'm not sure what a pure multiple is? Do you mean a power of 2? In which case still not quite (`6 >> 1 << 1 == 6`, for instance, even though it's not a power of 2)

Comment: but as the loop goes on it will fail, for 6 >> 2 << 2

Comment: @warl0ck it'll fail on powers of 2 also. Note my last comment ;). It doesn't really have anything to do with powers of 2 (except as intimately tied to the binary system)

Comment: apologies for the confusion, completely agree with you as ultimately this is just a simple binary trick or you can say bit manipulation to check if number is power of 2 or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's checking how many right-side bits are set to zero.

`>>` bitshifts right, then `<<` bitshifts left by the same amount.  Consider:

```
0b1000 >> 3 << 3
```

the first shift will do `0b1000 -> 0b0001`. The second will do `0b0001 -> 0b1000`. That's still equal to the original, so we're set.

Now let's see

```
0b1000 >> 4 << 4
```

the first shift will do `0b1000 -> 0b0000` because it shifts the one off the right side of the number. The second shift will try to shift back, but there's nothing to shift (`0 << n == 0` for any natural number n). The function is left to compare `0 != 0b1000` and of course breaks execution of the `for` block.

The function then returns `4-1`, which is `3`, which is how many zeroes are on the right side of the number.